# How to Solve a Composite Function

Tags: functions

If $f(x)=1+2x$ and $g(f(x))=x+3$, what is the value of $g(5)$? Help would be appreciated on how to solve this problem as there has been debate over the right answer ($5$ or $8$).

Comment: How do you get $5$ or $8$? That is very useful to help you.

Comment: $g(5)=g(1+2\cdot 2)=g(f(2))=2+3=5$

Answer (score 1):

Since we've been given the definition of $g(f(x))$, we may compute the $x$ values for which $f(x)=5$. That's $1+2x=5\implies x=2$, so $g(5)=2+3=5$ should be correct.